# try-catch around numeric increment

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen the following c# code:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();

try { 
   c.Counter++; 
} catch (Exception ex) {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); 
}
```

and was wondering, what purpose a `try{} catch(){}` around a numeric increment could possibly serve in the .NET world?

Comment: To catch overflow exceptions. Or whatever happens inside the property setter

Comment: @Steve C# has overflow exceptions disabled by default ... which is in contrast to VB.NET ...

Comment: unless wrapped in a checked, it does nothing.

Comment: To be honest, without knowing what `MyClass.Counter` looks like, we can't really comment. For all we know it might be `set { if (value == 5) throw /*...*/ }`. But if it's a simple numeric field/auto-property, that `try-catch` is pointless...

Comment: You will catch integer overflow exceptions (assuming `Counter` is an integer property and you're running with `checked` code), exceptions from the internal code (for instance, if setting the `Counter` property tries to log the change and this crashes), you will catch catastrophic runtime failures (in as much they can be catched at all), etc. Whatever can go wrong inside this property that can be catched, you will catch it.

Comment: If `MyClass.Counter` is an int property, it's nonsense. It would make sense if `MyClass.Counter` is not a numeric property and `++` operator is overloaded doing some weird thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To catch *integer overflow exception* [OverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx):

```
  // integer overflow policy (what the system should do if integer value
  // is out of [int.MinValue..int.MaxValue] range - 
  // throw the OverflowException or just allow the overflow) 
  // is regulated either explictly
  // by checked/unchecked keywords 
  // or implictly by /checked compiler directive, project settings etc.
  checked { // switch integer overflow check on to ensure OverflowException be thrown
    ...

    MyClass c = new MyClass();

    c.Counter = int.MaxValue; // maximum possible value

    try { 
      c.Counter++; // let's try to add up 1 to maximum possible value
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // ... And we'll have the exception thrown
      Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); 
    }

    ...
  }
```

Comment: `++` operator on `Int32.MaxValue` gives `Int32.MinValue` by default, without an exception.

Comment: You could include the fact, that this is due to a "mismatch" between C# (overflows disabled) and VB.NET (overflows enabled) :)

Comment: @decPL: that's why I've put `checked` - to *ensure* exception throwing

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair also not true for whitespace programming language ;>

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'm fairly certain `checked` wasn't there when I commented. One way or the other you might want to explain this explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` seems to be a property, so anything really can happen inside there (even DB access, access to a shared resource by multiple threads and so on). It won't be a good idea to do that of course, but technically nothing prevents one from doing so.

Comment: `Though I would advise against this type of Exception Handling at all. The place for Exception Handling is in it's own layer, not on each and every call. A good example is a generic filter in Web Api or Global.asax etc.`. Absolutely not true - the place of exception handling is at a place in code where you can react appropriately to an exception. A generic filter can be used to catch all unhandled exceptions, which is only part of the deal...

Comment: Well, this one does nothing but logs the error, so most likely it's not a good idea (since it can be done in one place) unless you want to just hide all exceptions happening which again is not that good, though there are some valid cases for that of course.

Comment: True - but the part I've quoted doesn't qualify that it applied for this specific case; to me (so probably to some others as well) it looks like a generic advice on exception handling, in which case it might be confusing to new developers, as it's simply untrue.

Comment: Ok, let's take the nice style of exception handling away. Though this was rather legitimate advice in my mind, just not so connected to this exact case as you say:).